# Pygame Sprite is leaving a trail behind when moved

Tags: python, pygame

I tried following the instructions to solve such problems online but none worked.
The problem is that even when I add a `screen.fill((255,255,255))` function, the trail is drawn.
here is my code:

```
import pygame 
x1=0;x2=0
y1=0;y2=30
black=(0,0,0)
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
import grass
grasslist=pygame.sprite.Group()
go=True
clock=pygame.time.Clock()
def create(what,x,y):
    global grasslist
    if what=='grass':
       block=grass.Grass() 
       grasslist.add(block)
       block.rect.x=x
       block.rect.y=y
while go:
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            go=False
    key=pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if key[pygame.K_a]:
        x1+=3
        
    create('grass',x1,y1)
    create('grass',x2,y2)
    screen.fill((255,255,255))
    grasslist.draw(screen)
    clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.flip()
        
pygame.quit()
```

grass is the module containing a sprite class named Grass
So how do I erase the previous sprites after the new sprite has been drawn?

Comment: You `create` 2 new objects every iteration of the loop. Create them once and in the loop move them.

Comment: @Deuce No. Please don't guess. A tuple is fine. See [`fill()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.fill).

Answer (score 2):

What is happening is the code is adding *two* new `Grass` objects to `grasslist` every frame, and drawing the whole sprite-group list every frame.  So after a few seconds of running, you have hundreds of `Grass` objects at various locations.  It *looks* like it's smearing across the window, but actually it's the previously-created `Grass` at the old position.

To fix this, just create the Grass object once, and change its `rect` rather than creating new ones:

```
import pygame
#import grass  Not supplied

x1=0;x2=0
y1=0;y2=30
black=(0,0,0)

# Dummy sprite class
class Grass( pygame.sprite.Sprite ):
    def __init__( self ):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__( self )
        self.image = pygame.image.load( "grass_small.png" ).convert_alpha()
        self.rect  = self.image.get_rect()

    def move( self, dx, dy ):
        self.rect.move_ip( dx, dy )

def create(what,x,y):
    global grasslist
    if what=='grass':
        #block=grass.Grass()
        block=Grass()
        grasslist.add(block)
        block.rect.x=x
        block.rect.y=y
    return block                            # return reference to new sprite

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))

grasslist = pygame.sprite.Group()
my_grass  = create( 'grass', 250, 250 )     # Single Grass object

go=True
clock=pygame.time.Clock()
while go:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            go=False

    key=pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if key[pygame.K_a]:
        my_grass.move( 3, 0 )              # Move just the object

    screen.fill((255,255,255))
    grasslist.draw(screen)
    clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: In this method, can I still check for collision using the grasslist group?

Comment: Thank you!! I didnt try your code as i couldnt understand the my_grasss.move part but the part where you explained that new rects are being made every iteration of the loop really helped.
So to solve the issue, i put a
grasslist.empty()
statement after the rects are drawn.
thank you!!!

Comment: @PythonNoob - Yes you can still check for collision in exactly the same way.  The `move()` simply changes the position of the sprite on-screen.  A sprite is always drawn wherever the `sprite.rect` x & y indicates, so the `.move()` function adjusts the position of the sprite by changing this rect.  The `move_ip()` function, is part of the Rect class, and just changes the location In Place.  You could also set rect.topleft, etc.

Comment: The problem with the move function is that now i'll have to write it for a lot of sprites. Is there any way to group all similar sprites and move them using one command?

Comment: @PythonNoob - Well you already have a sprite group, that's the best way of grouping them.  To move a bunch of sprites the same, just loop through each on in the group, calling it's `.move()`.  We're really only talking 2 lines of code.